# Django Admin Clear Field When Create New Object

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write a BookApp. Every time I create a new book, it's going to load chapter field from previous a book in the selection. How can I remove the relationship away but not deleting the content. I have also included pics.

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   def __str__(self):
      return self.name

class Chapter(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
   content = models.TextField()
   def __str__(self):
     return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
 category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    summary = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name`
```

And  in the admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from books.models import Category, Author, Chapter, Book

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('category', 'name', 'author', 'chapter')

admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Chapter)
admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

Here's the imag of problem.
[Added Book#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVxqT.png)

[Chapter of Book 1 still exist in loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMQsT.png)

Comment: did you tried this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete ?

Answer (score 1):

You have the foreign key relationship between `Book` and `Chapter` backwards: `Chapter` should have a foreign key to `Book`, not the other way around.